# Loading a separate JPanel/JInternalFrame into a separate JDesktopPane(in a JFrame)

Tags: java, swing, jframe, netbeans-7

Suppose I have a class `NewMDIApplication extends javax.swing.JFrame` which contains a `JDesktopPane` and a `JButton`. Also suppose I have another class `NewJInternalFrame extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame` or  `NewJPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel` which again contains some 'buttons' and 'text boxes' for performing some actions.

My intention is to load `NewJInternalFrame`'s object or `NewJPanel`'s object into `JDesktopPane` of `NewMDIApplication` when I click the `JButton`. 
Is it possible to be done? If yes, how to do this?

Comment: You probably should not be extending `JFrame`, `JInternalFrame` **or** `JPanel`.  In answer to your question, yes it is possible.  As to how, what part are you having trouble with?  Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of your current code with a specific question.

Comment: Actually Im designing `gui` using `netbeans' drag and drop functionality which automatically creates the codes. So, it would be troublesome if remove extends part. Both   `NewMDIApplication` and `NewJPanel`  are separate classes. I want to know which method should be used to load `NewJPanel`'s object into `JDesktopPane`.

here is the code for both the classes:
    public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

Comment: *"Actually Im designing gui using netbeans'"*  It sounds like Netbeans is doing the 'doing' and you are its slave.  I suggest you get around this by stop using Netbeans and learn how to code Java.  As it is, I doubt anyone will be able to give you the 'magic incantation' to make Netbeans do this.

Comment: surely I'll try to code my myself. I tried doing this
 `private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
       
       new NewJInternalFrame().setVisible(true);
        jDesktopPane1.add(new NewJInternalFrame());
       jDesktopPane1.validate();
    } ` 
 but nothing happens i.e when clicked on the buttons , internal frame doesn't appear. please suggest the correct way. Pardon me if I committed any mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example of adding `JInternalFrame` instances to a `JDesktopPane`.  Note that you need to set a **size** or they do not appear.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class FrameWithInternalFrames {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // the GUI as seen by the user (without frame)
            JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            gui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(2, 3, 2, 3));

            gui.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 100));
            gui.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

            final JDesktopPane dtp = new JDesktopPane();
            gui.add(dtp, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            JButton newFrame = new JButton("Add Frame");

            ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
            private int disp = 10;
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JInternalFrame jif = new JInternalFrame();
                dtp.add(jif);
                jif.setLocation(disp, disp);
                jif.setSize(100,100); // VERY important!
                disp += 10;
                jif.setVisible(true);
            }
            };
            newFrame.addActionListener(listener);

            gui.add(newFrame, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

            JFrame f = new JFrame("Demo");
            f.add(gui);
            // Ensures JVM closes after frame(s) closed and
            // all non-daemon threads are finished
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            // See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7143398/418556 for demo.
            f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

            // ensures the frame is the minimum size it needs to be
            // in order display the components within it
            f.pack();
            // should be done last, to avoid flickering, moving,
            // resizing artifacts.
            f.setVisible(true);
        }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 You can also `pack()` the internal frame, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7220544/230513), to leverage its layout.